# Compare two Maps in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, compare

I want to be able to compare two arrays (which will hold values of the same XML but different ages, so i can see if any changed have been made). I have two arrays, one contains attributes and values of the older XML line that i have parsed, and the other contains attributes and latest version of that same XML line that in have parsed.

Example:

```
Array1:                                                                         

rect x="220.00"                    
width="300.00" 
id="rect_1" 
y="180.00" 
height="280.00" 

Array2:                                                                         

rect x="300.00"                    
width="400.00" 
id="rect_1" 
height="280.00"
info = "description"

etc etc
```

So here, the changes would be:

- The `rect x` attribute has changed from 220 (array1) to 300 (array2)
- the `width` attribute has changed from 300 (array1) to 400(array2)
- Array2 has gained an attribute called `info`
- `y` has been removed from array2

How would I compare two arrays and display results like that? Basically I want it to show changes and differences.

Heres the code i tried:

```
Collection<String> listOne = Arrays.asList(array1);

Collection<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList(array);

Collection<String> similar = new HashSet<String>( listOne );
Collection<String> different = new HashSet<String>();
different.addAll( listOne );
different.addAll( listTwo );

similar.retainAll( listTwo );
different.removeAll( similar );

resultsBuff.append("\nDifferences: \n"+ different + "\n\nChanges: \n" + similar);
```

This code didn't quite do what I wanted it to do (as described earlier).

Comment: They aren't arrays but maps, are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no choice but to loop through both Arrays.
I would loop through the attributes, split key and value and build a HashMap for each array.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>() 
for (String attribute : array1) {    
  String[] splitted = attribute.split("=");   
  map1.put(splitted[0], splitted[1]); 
}
```

Do the same to create map2.

```
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
...
```

Loop through first map and verify if key/value is different or exist in map2 to detected attribute removal.

```
for (String key : map1.keySet()) {    
  if (!map2.containsKey(key)) {
    System.out.println(key + "has been removed from Array2" )
  } else if (!map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key)) {
    System.out.println(key + "attribute has changed from " + map1.get(key) + " to " + map2.get(key)  );
  } 
}
```

Loop through map2 to detect new attributes

```
for (String key : map2.keySet()) {    
  if (!map1.containsKey(key)) {
    System.out.println(key + "has been added to Array2" );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great, thanks! When looping through map2, it displays the results multiple times for some reason though!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a HashMap instead of an array, because it is better suited for this kind of key/value structures:

```
map.put("rect x","220.00");
map.put("width","300.00");
...
```

Build 2 hashmaps from the 2 arrays, and compare them:

```
if(!map1.equals(map2)) { //something has changed
    //loop over keys and compare values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object holding this information and implement a custom equals. You dont need to use an array as a data structure. You can use an object.

For example

```
public class MyObject{
    private double rect_x;
    private double width;
    private double id;
    private double y;
    private double height

    //usual getters and setters
    //implement hashcode
    //implemement equals eg
    public boolean equals (Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof MyObject)){
             return false;
        }
        MyObject that=  MyObject.class.cast(o);
        return this.width == that.width && this.id == that.id etc etc
    }

}
```

Comment: The content is dynamic, taken from an XML. Your class is static.

Comment: Correct, i will be applying this to a line that will change depending on the situation

Comment: ah ok - understookd. I didnt get the dynamic part of the question -sorry

Answer (score 0):

You already have maps? or they are just arrays?
I mean, are those "labels" implicit or not?
If they're not and you actually have two Map, you could easily do something like:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,String> pair : array1){
    String key = pair.getKey();
    String value = pair.getValue();
    if(!array2.containsKey(key)){
        System.out.println("Array2 lost attribute " + key);
    }else{
        String value2 = array2.get(key);
        if(!value.equals(value2){
            System.out.println("The '"+key+"' attribute  has changed from "+value+" to "+ value2 ;
        }
        array2.remove(key);
    }
}

for(Map.Entry<String,String> pair : array2){
    String key = pair.getKey();
    System.out.println("Array2 gained attribute " + key);
}
```

If you don't have the explicit labels, you just create another mapping before this code and use it to build two maps....

Comment: if they're just arrays, how do you know what label to give to something that is added or removed??
Can new things be added only to array2 and only at its tail?